# Remove a div of currently uploaded item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**==== UPDATED QUESTION ====**

**I have control over onComplete state. That's not the case. The problem is that I don't know how to remove currently uploaded item's Progress Bar**. Pls, check the screenshot.

I am using a jQuery plugin for multiupload with the support of HTML5 File API located on this [website named **damnUploader**](https://github.com/safronizator/damnUploader).

File upload works fine, but I'm stuck at the point where I need to hide the uploading progress bar once the upload is finished, but do not know how to do it without any special key to tell to remove progress bar from that element.

**==== UPDATED QUESTION ====**

To clarify my question, here is a screenshot. 5th and 6th images are at the uploading state. 6th image is about to be finished, so once it's successfully uploaded, I want to hide that progress bar which is below that image, but without touching the other progress bars on the other items.

[image]

Here is the javascript code (just search the function where is `console.log(this._id);` line:

```
var announcements = function () {

    /*** ******************** ***/
    /*** 1.1 MAIN INIT METHOD ***/
    function _init() {
        // Main inits on document ready state
    }

    /*** ********************* ***/
    /*** 1.2 PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ***/

    function _form_upload(){

        // Main form for fallbacks
        var $form_form = $('#form');

        // Standard input file
        var $form_file_input = $('#file_uploader');

        // File POST field name (for ex., it will be used as key in $_FILES array, if you using PHP)
        var $form_file_fieldName = 'image-file';

        // Upload url
        var $form_file_url = '/announcements/form_file_upload/' + $form_file_fieldName;

        // List of available thumbnail previews based on selected files
        var $form_file_list = $('#form_file_list');

        // File upload progress
        var $form_file_progress = $('#form_file_progress');

        // Settings
        var $form_file_autostartOn = true;
        var $form_file_previewsOn = true;

        // Misc
        var isImgFile = function(file) {
            return file.type.match(/image.*/);
        };
        var imagesCount = $form_file_list.length + 1;

        var templateProgress = $form_file_list.find('div.progress').remove().wrap('<div/>').parent().html()
        var template = $form_file_list.html()

        // File uploader init
        $form_file_input.damnUploader({
            // URL of server-side upload handler
            url: $form_file_url,
            // File POST field name
            fieldName:  $form_file_fieldName,
            // Container for handling drag&drops (not required)
            dropBox: $('html'),
            // Expected response type ('text' or 'json')
            dataType: 'JSON',
            // Multiple selection
            multiple: false
        });

        // Creates queue table row with file information and upload status
        var createRowFromUploadItem = function(ui) {
            var $row = $('<div class="col-xs-4"/>').appendTo($form_file_list);
            var $progressBar = $('<div/>').addClass('progress-bar progress-bar-success').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuemin', 0).attr('aria-valuemax', 100);
            var $pbWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('progress').append($progressBar);

            // Defining cancel button & its handler
            /*
            var $cancelBtn = $('<a/>').attr('href', 'javascript:').append(
                    $('<span/>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove')
                ).on('click', function() {
                    var $statusCell =  $pbWrapper.parent();
                    $statusCell.empty().html('<i>cancelled</i>');
                    ui.cancel();
                    console.log((ui.file.name || "[custom-data]") + " canceled");
                });
            */

            // Generating preview
            var $preview;
            if ($form_file_previewsOn) {
                if (isImgFile(ui.file)) {
                    // image preview (note: might work slow with large images)
                    $preview = $('<img/>').attr('width', 120);
                    ui.readAs('DataURL', function(e) {
                        $preview.attr('src', e.target.result);
                    });
                } else {
                    // plain text preview
                    $preview = $('<i/>');
                    ui.readAs('Text', function(e) {
                        $preview.text(e.target.result.substr(0, 15) + '...');
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $preview = $('<i class="fa fa-image"></i>');
            }

            // Constructing thumbnails markup
            $('<div class="thumbnail"/>').append($preview).appendTo($row);
            $row.find('.thumbnail').append('<button type="button" name="formImageRemove" value="imageRemove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button" />');
            $row.find('.thumbnail').prepend(loading);
            $row.find('.uploading').append($pbWrapper);
            $row.find('button').append('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o" />');

            return $progressBar;
        };

        // File adding handler
        var fileAddHandler = function(e) {
            // e.uploadItem represents uploader task as special object,
            // that allows us to define complete & progress callbacks as well as some another parameters
            // for every single upload
            var ui = e.uploadItem;
            var filename = ui.file.name || ""; // Filename property may be absent when adding custom data

            // We can replace original filename if needed
            if (!filename.length) {
                ui.replaceName = "custom-data";
            } else if (filename.length > 14) {
                ui.replaceName = filename.substr(0, 10) + "_" + filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
            }

            // Show info and response when upload completed
            var $progressBar = createRowFromUploadItem(ui);

            ui.completeCallback = function(success, data, errorCode) {
                // Original filename
                // console.log((this.file.name || "[custom-data]"));
                if (success) {
                    // Add animation class for fadeout
                    $(this).find('.loading').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
                    console.log(this._id);
                    console.log(ui);
                    // Add some data to POST in upload request once upload finished and new filename retrieved
                    ui.addPostData($form_form.serializeArray()); // from array
                    ui.addPostData('images[]', JSON.parse(data).file_name); // .. or as field/value pair

                } else {
                    console.log('uploading failed. Response code is:', errorCode);
                }
            };

            // Updating progress bar value in progress callback
            ui.progressCallback = function(percent) {
                $progressBar.css('width', Math.round(percent) + '%');
            };

            // To start uploading immediately as soon as added
            $form_file_autostartOn && ui.upload();
        };

        var loading = function(){
            return '<div class="loading">\n\t<div class="uploading animated fadeInUp">\n\t\t<img src="/assets/img/loaders/ajax-loader.gif" />\n\t</div>\n</div>';
        }

        // File Uploader events
        $form_file_input.on({
            'du.add' : fileAddHandler,

            'du.limit' : function() {
                console.error("File upload limit exceeded!");
            },

            'du.completed' : function() {
                console.info('******');
                console.info("All uploads completed!");
            }
        });

    }

    /*** ************************************************** ***/
    /*** 1.3 MAKE PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ACCESSIBLE FROM OUTSIDE ***/
    return {
        init: function () {
            _init();
        },
        form_upload:function(){
            _form_upload();
        }
    };

}();

$(document).ready(function () {
    announcements.init();
});
```

Comment: Looking at your link: `du.completed - fired once when all uploads completed` might be the place to start. It's under `events`

Comment: @MattBurland - yes! but the problem is - I do not know how to remove a progress bar from currently uploaded item and not from all of the available items.

Comment: You might be looking for jQuery's `.then()` function. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: [These examples may help you.](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - thank you for your comment, but this isn't the problem, the problem is to tell to hide currently finished item's div element. I have a control over the finished state event, but the problem is in selector

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I really think I can provide an answer to this. If you are still looking for a solution I need the HTML markup from your upload(s). I use damnuploader as well and am interested in a solution also but it's HTML specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom event and trigger it with Jquery:

```
$( "#hide_loading" ).on( "done", function() {
    ( "#hide_loading" ).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 5000);
});

if ( success ) {
    $( ".hide_loading").trigger( "loadingfade" );
}
```

and if you completely want to remove it from the DOM structure after the animation:

```
$( "#hide_loading" ).on( "loadingfade", function() {
    $( ".hide_loading" ).animate({
        //put animations here (don't forget cross browser compatibility)
        opacity: 0,
    }, 5000, function() { //this function is called when the animation is completed
        $( "#hide_loading" ).remove();
    });
});
```

(now just add the class `hide_loading` to your loading elements)